# Export Excel via AJAX from VB.NET WebMethod As Binary?

Tags: jquery, ajax, export-to-excel, webmethod

I can make the excel file within a WebMethod easily enough, but what should the WebMethod Function be to be able to send the file to the client?

I'd like to jQuery .get (or whatever is required) the file from a WebMethod, but I don't know how the function should export.

Looked for "as binary", but didn't see anything like that.

My site is jQuery/AJAX/.NET WebMethod, and I'd like to avoid server side scripting.  If there's a better method than what I'm trying to do, please suggest that instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first of all , GET is not allowed in ASP.Net webmethods , write everything always as POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is really more for getting json or xml data from the server ,  It might be easier to save the file on the server after it is created , then on client side give them the link to the file for them to download

Comment: so no webmethod version of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425840/how-to-export-a-dataset-to-excel-and-raise-a-file-download-dialog-from-asp-net-w ?  Thank-you very much for responding